# Javascript - Use closures sparingly? 

Tags: javascript

I'm watching http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU, and at about 13:37 (hehe), he shows a slide of a list of things to avoid due to the addition of a new object onto the scope chain.

I understand what he's saying with `using` and `try-catch` statements, as well as accessing out-of-scope variables, but I don't understand why closures should be avoided. If the closure's local variables are going to be on the top of the scope chain, where's the performance loss?

Comment: Just remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil. The video is discussing making JavaScript more performant, however most JavaScript never needs to be optimized. If you've got a call to a function set up asynchronously after a user clicks a button, the user will never notice the difference between a 30ms response rate and a 40ms response rate.

Comment: The answers here are all good. Remember, though, that the video is a couple of years old, and may not be as relevant as t once was.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because, to look up variables that are not local, the VM has to walk up the scope chain to find them. Local variables, on the other hand, are cached, so a local variable lookup is much faster. The more nested a function is, the longer the scope chain becomes, and the more the potential performance impact increases.

This is partly why you often see code like this in popular JS libraries:

```
(function(window, document, undefined) {
  // ...
})(window, document);
```

Here, `window` and `document` become local variables, so looking them up becomes much faster, which becomes pretty noticeable if you reference these objects thousands of times from within your code.

[This page](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIRExSc) has a really in-depth description of scope chains and execution contexts. (The entire article is interesting if you have the time to read it.)

Overall, though, modern browsers optimize all of this stuff to the point where it's basically negligible, so it's not something I would worry about.

Comment: This is right, it's because Closures store references to local variables rather then copies, so it forces a stack walk rather then a local lookup.

Comment: I mean a closure that doesn't access out-of-scope variables. It seemed a bit redundant for him to say to avoid accessing out-of-scope variables, and then explicitly say avoid closures. It seems implied that he means in addition to using local variables, you should also avoid closures. Am I misinterpreting what he's saying?

Comment: @Walkerneo: It's not a closure if you aren't referencing non-local variables. What he's saying is you should avoid closures whenever possible, but when you *have* to reference an out-of-scope variable, you should use a local variable to make the lookup faster (if you use the variable often from within that function--otherwise it won't do much).

Comment: @musicfreak, !! Awesome!! Thanks for mentioning the part about javascript libraries. I had wondered that a few times but never asked, and I'm not sure I would have understood without watching the video. This clears things up a lot! Thanks so much!

Comment: @musicfreak—do you have any performance benchmarks? I've never seen that pattern used soley for performance, I doubt it has any benefit at all - it **creates** an extra scopt object, so *window* and *document* are at the same place they would have been without the IIFE. And some browsers are *very* fast at global variable resolution, slower for scope chain (I'll assume compiler optimisations are the cause). An IIFE is usually used to get safe references to the global object and undefined (which is trivial to do without the closure).

Comment: @musicfreak—incidentally, scope chains are static (except for *with*) so I doubt browsers actaully "walk" them for identifier resolution. Scope chains are created once when the function is called, at that point all accessible variables can be made properties of the current execution context, including globals.

Comment: I think that pattern you showed is more for preventing a silly user from overwriting important global constants and less for performance issues.

Comment: @missingno: Hmm, but aren't arguments put at the top of the scope chain? So wouldn't they be as fast as local variables? I understand modern engines optimize all of this, but for the others, I'd think there would be a performance gain there, if minor. In any case, I remember a post by (I think) John Resig that claimed there is a performance difference. If you can prove me wrong, I will gladly edit my post.

Comment: @RobG: True about scope chains being static, but I think browsers only recently (relatively speaking) started treating them as such. I remember a couple years ago this was still considered a pretty Big Deal. Now it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 9):

[The linked video explains why closure can inflict some performance hits starting about 11:08.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU#t=11m05s)

Basically, he's saying that for each nested function, it adds another object to the scope chain and therefore accessing variables outside of the closure will take even longer.

To find the value associated with a variable, the Javascript interprer follows this process:

1. search the local scope object
2. if 1 didn't work, search the parent scope object
3. if 2 didn't work, search the parent's parent scope object
4. keep searching parent scopes until
5. you search the global scope
6. and if it's still not found, throw an undefined variable error.

In a normal function, to find a variable, you only have to search at the top of the scope chain. A closure, on the other hand, to find parent variables will have to search down the scope chain, sometimes several levels deep. For example, if you had some closures like this (note that this is a *very contrived example*):

```
function a (x) {
  function b (y) {
    return (function (z) {
      return x + y + z;
    })(y + y);
  }
  return b(x + 3);
}
```

From the innermost function, to evaluate the expression `x + y + z`, it has to traverse up three levels in the scope chain to find x, then it has to traverse up the scope chain again two levels to find y, and then finally once to find z. In total, it had to search *six objects* in the scope chain to return the final result.

This is unavoidable in closures, because **closures always have to access parent variables**. If they didn't there would be no purpose in using a closure.

Also note that in Javascript, there is a significant overhead in creating functions, especially closures. Take, for example, this fairly simple closure:

```
function a(x) {
  return function (y) {
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

And you call it several different times, like this

```
var x = a(1);
var y = a(2);
var z = a(3);
alert(x(3)); // 4
alert(y(3)); // 5
alert(z(3)); // 6
```

You'll notice that the function returned from `a` has to keep what was passed as an argument in the parent function even after the parent function has already been called. This means that the interpreter has to keep in memory what you passed in to every function that you have called so far.

Comment: Would storing `y` and `z` as local variables in the third function still reduce performance? Of course, for this example, there isn't a reason for creating the closures, but what about when there is?

Comment: @Walkerneo It will still have to go up the scope chain to find the parent variables. If you use the parent variables more than once in the inner function, it will be worth declaring as local variables, but if you only use them once, there's nothing helpful about declaring them as local variables.

Comment: Alright, I understand the problem with traversing the scope chain, but, like I said in my comment on the other answer, the way he put "use closures sparingly" right after what he says about out-of-scope variables makes it seem like there's something inherently wrong with closures and not just that they add another object to the scope chain.

Comment: @Walkerneo: If  you watch the part of the video that Peter is referencing, he talks specifically about what we're talking about: the scope chain. That's the problem with closures. However, closures are obviously unavoidable in real code, so he's saying that you should declare a local variable for every out-of-scope variable you reference, to make future lookups faster.

Comment: @Walkerneo There's nothing inherently wrong with closures--they are absolutely wonderful things IMO. There's just a problem that they incur some performance overhead.